# Dual boot Endeavour OS changed to EFI hard drive after BIOS update

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, dual-boot, uefi

I dual booted windows 11 and Endeavor OS on my HP notebook without any problem, but after a BIOS update the Boot options menu listed Endeavour os as EFI hard drive.

[image: Image showing problem]

Also now the OS boot manager doesn't show Endeavour os as another OS and thus cannot choose the os on bootup.

[image: Image showing problem]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly modified [answer by telcoM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475245/400135) to fit your question.

Your UEFI upgrade has probably reset the NVRAM settings, which on UEFI systems also include the boot configuration for installed operating systems. Not all the boot menu items are detected on-the-fly at boot time: instead, the boot items for installed operating systems are stored in UEFI NVRAM at OS installation time.

You can boot from any UEFI-capable Linux Live media, verify that the EndeavourOS GRUB bootloader is still present in the ESP partition, and use the `efibootmgr` command to add a boot menu item for it.

Assuming that your EFI System Partition is the first partition on `/dev/sda`, the necessary `efibootmgr` command line should be similar to this:

```
# efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -l \\EFI\\EndeavourOS\\grubx64.efi -L "Arch Linux"
```

Note the Windows-style path name for the bootloader, with doubled backslashes since a backslash is a special escape character for the shell. For the boot menu label (the -L option), you can write anything you want instead of "EndeavourOS Linux", if you wish.

Comment: I actually reinstalled grub and it does appear in the boot menu, but I am not able to change the order and I also tried changing the order from EasyUEFI but it resets every time I reboot, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I also tried your solution but that didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by first re-installing grub in root and then later changing the OS boot manager order in the BIOS, which solved the problem.