# Grub disappeared from boot menu

Tags: arch-linux, grub

My grub suddenly disappeared from boot menu. Using win11 and arch linux dual boot.
Did not update BIOS or made any changes.

I tried the answer from this similiar problem but it didn't help:
[GRUB disappeared from Boot Menu after UEFI (BIOS) upgrade on Thinkpad X1 Carbon gen5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473157/grub-disappeared-from-boot-menu-after-uefi-bios-upgrade-on-thinkpad-x1-carbon)

What to do to get it back?

Comment: Comment for user Joepie: "Did you get any updates for Windows 11? This would probably put back the Windows bootloader as primairy. You can use your Arch-stick ( from which you installed your OS ) to reinstall Grub.
Or you can install Grub2win in your Windows and set this as primairy bootloader. Configure it and you should be on your way."

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall `grub` if you boot form the usb-stick/dvd you used to install `Arch`. You open the `Terminal` and type

> sudo pacman install grub

Or you can install `grub2win` in Windows, make it the default bootloader, and configure it. This program is grub made for Windows.

You could also install rEFInd, which is another bootloader.